# Do file locks stay when you use open for a second time?

Tags: perl, file, file-io

Suppose:

```
my $fh;
open $fh, ">>", "file.txt";
flock($fh, LOCK_EX);
open $fh, "+<", "file.txt";
close $fh;
```

Will the file lock stay or will it be released? If it will be released is there a way to make it stay ?
I cloud not find relevant information.

Comment: it probably won't stay, since gc in perl is very simple refcount, so after 4th line is executed, the original handler will have 0 ref then get collected then trigger auto close. you just need different variable to hold the handler. just guessing, maybe wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `open` on a filehandle that is already assigned to an open file descriptor performs an implicit close on the filehandle. And closing a locked filehandle releases the lock.

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do by opening the same file with the same filehandle in two different modes. What if you used a second filehandle?

```
open my $fh, ">>", "file.txt";
flock($fh, LOCK_EX);
open my $fh2, "+<", "file.txt";
... rewrite 'file.txt' with $fh2 ...
close $fh2;   # done with rewrite
close $fh;    # done with lock
```

---

It looks like `flock` is respected for a file in `+<` mode (works in Linux, this might not be portable), so with that and some `seek` statements, you only need a single filehandle.

```
# make sure file exists before you use '+<' mode
{ open my $touch,'>>','file.txt'; }

open my $fh, '+<', 'file.txt';
flock $fh, LOCK_EX;

seek $fh, 0, 2;
print $fh 'stuff for the end of the file';

seek $fh, 0, 0;
print $fh 'something for the start of the file';

close $fh;  # releases lock
```

Comment: The code below the HR introduces a race condition if the person holding the lock is allowed to delete the file.

Answer (score 3):

No, you will lose the lock because the second `open` call on the same file handle implicitly closes the original one first.

What are you trying to do? It looks as though you want to keep the file entirely to yourself, in which case I recommend creating a temporary file with [`File::Temp`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Temp) and locking that as a flag. Then other processes will request the lock that they want on the same temporary file, and can then go ahead and work on `file.txt` when they get it.

Do you realise that `flock` is *cooperative*, so it won't stop another process from doing what it likes with the file unless it is also using `flock` and waiting for the access to be granted?

Comment: @Bloodcount: If you explain your problem, rather than asking how to implement your solution, then we will be able to help you much better. Perhaps in another question?

Comment: I want to rewrite a flag in the beginning of the file after appending to it. I don't want the file to be touched by other processes(if possible) until I am finished with rewriting the flag

Comment: @Bloodcount: If that flag is a single character, or has the same length whether it is set or clear, then you can write it in a single operation, so there is no need for a lock. Otherwise you will need to rewrite the whole file. I think you need to ask a new question.

Comment: The flag is always 4 bytes. I am doing a simple storage to better understand working with files and so on. Basically my concern is that if I have another thread which wants to write as well there may be a race condition for the state of the flag.

Comment: I had some issues when using it, although it was my fault. Anyways, one of the things which I've learned from this question is as the accepted answer states: "open closes the original file handle"

Comment: @Bloodcount: You can rewrite just those four bytes (in fact just the relevant disk blocks) in a single operation. Another thread will always see the data before or after it has been modified, but it should communicate with the main process to change the data on the disk. Please open a new question, as this has gone too far off topic.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rely on it on whatever behaviour you observe.

---

I think you're trying to open a file handle for read-writing, creating it if necessary, but without clobbering any existing content, and that you've discovered that `open` can't do all three.

Instead of two uses of `open`, use the following:

```
use Fcntl qw( O_RDWR O_CREAT LOCK_EX );

sysopen(my $fh, "file.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666)
   or die($!);
flock($fh, LOCK_EX)
   or die($!);
```

Using [File::Temp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Temp) could make your life easier.

Comment: You might be tempted to use something more restrictive than `0666`. Don't. Use `0666` (or `0777` for dirs and executable files) and let the user decided how restricted he actually wants it using their umask.

Comment: `O_TRUNC` is the flag that would cause the file to be clobbered if it exists.